# Can't start/stop openshift application

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools

I have an application on openshift which has suddenly stopped running.
The following cartridges are used :

- Mysql
- Cron
- Nodejs

The only information about the crash of the app is the following from nodejs.log :

```
 DEBUG: Sending SIGTERM to child...
```

Now, when I try to rhc start / stop / restart the app, I got the following messages :

```
Failed to execute: 'control stop' for /var/lib/openshift/<username>/nodejs
Failed to execute: 'control stop' for /var/lib/openshift/<username>/cron
Failed to execute: 'control stop' for /var/lib/openshift/<username>/mysql
```

I can manually start the app by ssh in the app and executing

```
./mysql/bin/control start
./nodejs/bin/control start
./cron/bin/control start
```

Why can't the app be automatically restarted ?

Comment: @timo.rieber Please stop adding the same tag to many posts to earn some extra reputation. You're not really helping the community here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution that worked for me - as weird as it is - try a day later.

Had the same problem yesterday - neither restarting nor git pushes were working. Tried restoring from snapshot, forcing stop and manual starts to no avail. And today it works straight off. I can only guess that some cron-jobs on OpenShift fixed it.

Comment: Well, you are right. Tried today and there were no problem anymore. Kind of weird. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try 'rhc app-force-stop  "app"'. Then restart the app.  I don't know what the root cause  of your problem is tho.   Check your disk quota and or a memory leak.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment.  Quota is fine and force-stop does work, but I can't start the app with rhc. I have to manually start all the cartridges

Comment: My app is python based so I'm not sure how Nodejs works.  Did you check the build logs when you push your app for action hook errors?

Comment: To answer the question above, _rhc app start/stop/restart_ were not working. The _rhc app force-stop_ didn't give any errors.