# Failed to execute: 'control update-cluster' for /var/lib/openshift/<user_id>/haproxy

Tags: django, python-2.7, openshift

I can't restart, force stop, remove cartridges, delete the application, see the logs or add new keys. Basically I can do nothing. I think my app is corrupted somehow. I would like to delete this one and create a new one but in the future, if this happens again I would like to understand why.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem 2 days ago, and I was not the only one.
In my case the problem was fixed the next day without any intervention of my own.

Take a look here for more info : [Can't start/stop openshift application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25377576/cant-start-stop-openshift-application)